# Boost Spirit is incorrect parsing

Tags: c++, boost

I have a following code:

```
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
std::string input("d:/std/prte/type.spr#12");
std::string::iterator strbegin = input.begin();
std::pair<std::string, int> p;
qi::parse(
    strbegin, 
    input.end(),
    *qi::char_ >> '#' >> qi::int_,       // parser grammar 
    p
);
```

I want to get `("d:/std/prte/type.spr", 12)`, but I got `("d:/std/prte/type.spr#12", 0)`.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spirit does not do backoffs like regular expressions do.  `*char_` will capture as many characters as possible, hence grabbing the entire string.  If you check the return from parse, it should indicate that you failed to match because, after consuming `d:/std/prte/type.spr#12` as `*char_`, it could not find a `#`

The solution should be to change it to `*(char_ - '#') >> # >> int_`

Comment: Note: when spirit fails to parse, it leaves the cursor where it failed, because that is very helpful for printing error messages.

Comment: +1, I went into a little more detail regarding the error checking.

Comment: @CortAmmon `when spirit fails to parse, it leaves the cursor where it failed` are you sure? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e07ab411bbbaab1

Comment: I could be wrong in qi.  I haven't gotten to upgrade to that yet.  In classic, parse() returns an info object, indicating whether there is a match and where the cursor is, and that cursor is moved (I use it for debuggin all the time)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to check the result of parsing: See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5e3ef45b3669472)** clearly prints:

```
Parse failed
Remaining unparsed: 'd:/std/prte/type.spr#12'
```

Here's the error handling code for future reference:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    std::string input("d:/std/prte/type.spr#12");
    std::string::const_iterator iter = input.begin(), end = input.end();
    std::pair<std::string, int> p;
    bool ok = qi::parse(iter, end,
            *qi::char_ >> '#' >> qi::int_,       // parser grammar 
            p
        );

    if (ok)
        std::cout << "Parse success\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";


    if (iter != end)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(iter,end) << "'\n";
}
```

Of course, you want non-greedy match until `#`:

```
        *(qi::char_ - '#') >> '#' >> qi::int_,       // parser grammar
```

Also look at BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE to debug your rules:

```
qi::rule<It, std::string()> srule = *qi::char_;
qi::rule<It, int()> irule         = qi::int_;
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((srule)(irule))

It iter = input.begin(), end = input.end();
bool ok = qi::parse(iter, end,
        srule >> '#' >> irule,       // parser grammar 
        p
    );
```

Would print

```
<srule>
  <try>d:/std/prte/type.spr#12</try>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[d, :, /, s, t, d, /, p, r, t, e, /, t, y, p, e, ., s, p, r, #, 1, 2]]</attributes>
</srule>
Parse failed
Remaining unparsed: 'd:/std/prte/type.spr#12'
```

As you can see **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3cb376a569fff11)** as well

Comment: added a demo of using BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG to debug your rules

Comment: Printing `Remaining unparsed` doesn't make any sense if parse failed. In this partucular example it be helpful to print **empty** string, meaning that `qi::char_` rule "eat" the whole input. For example, using expectation point: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66b4a5931217fc92. +1 for debug rule, anyway)

Comment: If you mean that the wording "Remaining unparsed" could be confusing, maybe. I think it's spot on! The **parse failed**, completely. The source iterator is _at the start of input_ after the attempted parse. (_Expectation points have implications reaching beyond of what I wanted to present here, but yes, they too report the source location with three iterators._). Actually,